# How to properly set up the V8 Debug Configuration in Eclipse with Nodeclipse for NodeJS

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

**Back in the day** I was debugging `node.js` applications using the [ChromeDevTools](https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/). Breakpoints would be synced or reset on remote, so that no matter what, the breakpoints in the Eclipse breakpoint window would always match the actual breakpoints.

Also, setting up the Source Mapping as [described here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/FeatureDebugOnRealFiles) would cause Eclipse to break inside my actual local files, not in a read-only V8 window.

**These days**, ChromeDevTools is outdated and unmaintained. I started using Nodeclipse and their V8 debugger.

But now, when debugging, Eclipse keeps breaking on breakpoints I had already unset or removed. Seemingly irregardless of my setting here:

[image]

Also, whether or not it's a break point I meant to break on, A new read-only editor opens with the V8 (Chromium) icon in stead of the javascript-icon. If the original name was e.g. `index.js`, the script that opens is `index.js (20).chromium`.

What is changed? How exactly does one set up the Nodeclipse V8 debugger for proper breakpoint syncing and source mapping?

Answer (score 0):

There is nice intro info given, but still a discussion should follow, that does not fit to StackOverflow format. Please create and follow with an issue on https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues

These days, (since Nodecipse 0.2) Launch configuration is created automatically, so most users may even don't know about it existence. And it is needed to be recalled looking at code how actually launch configurations are created and synced. Related source are here:
 https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/src/org/nodeclipse/debug/launch